# Add placeholder rows to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of dataframes.

```
# Split dataframe into list of dataframes on two factor variables.
DF_list <- split(DF, list(DF$Unit_number, DF$Compartment), drop = TRUE)
```

I know how to remove rows from lists of dataframes. But this time I want to add rows. 
1 placeholder row on the bottom of every dataframe in the list.

This will prevent my rate of change calculations from creating false calculations for different factor levels that buttress each other in the normal dataframe structure.

Before splitting on compartment and unit number the dataframe looks like this;

```
DF <- data.frame(Unit_number=c(1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1),
                 Compartment=c("Engine", "Engine", "Engine", "Transmission", "Transmission", "Transmission", "Tyres", "Tyres", "Tyres", "Tyres"))
```

The result needed is this;

```
Result <- data.frame(Unit_number=c(1,1,"Placeholder",2,"Placeholder",2,2,"Placeholder",1,"Placeholder",2,2,"Placeholder",1,1),
                 Compartment=c("Engine", "Engine","Placeholder", "Engine","Placeholder", "Transmission", "Transmission","Placeholder", "Transmission","Placeholder", "Tyres", "Tyres","Placeholder", "Tyres", "Tyres"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the same place holder that we want to add at the bottom of every list, we can create a `Placeholder_df` and `rbind` it at the end of every list.

Using `purrr` , `map_dfr` we could do

```
Placeholder_df <-data.frame(Unit_number = "Placeholder",
                            Compartment = "Placeholder")

purrr::map_dfr(DF_list, ~ rbind(., Placeholder_df))

#   Unit_number  Compartment
#1            1       Engine
#2            1       Engine
#3  Placeholder  Placeholder
#4            2       Engine
#5  Placeholder  Placeholder
#6            1 Transmission
#7  Placeholder  Placeholder
#8            2 Transmission
#9            2 Transmission
#10 Placeholder  Placeholder
#11           1        Tyres
#12           1        Tyres
#13 Placeholder  Placeholder
#14           2        Tyres
#15           2        Tyres
#16 Placeholder  Placeholder
```

---

In base R, we could do

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(DF_list, function(x) rbind(x, Placeholder_df)))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we can make use of `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(rbind, DF_list, list(Placeholder_df)))
```

#### data

```
Placeholder_df <-data.frame(Unit_number = "Placeholder",
                        Compartment = "Placeholder")
```